# nginx returning 301 without any rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a wordpress site with the configuration below:

```
ian@ianhobson:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ cat thecoachmasternetwork
# Statements for thecoachmasternetwork.com
#
# rewrites of http to https at bottom of file
server {

server_name thecoachmasternetwork.com www.thecoachmasternetwork.com;

listen 80;
fastcgi_read_timeout  300;

root /var/www/thecoachmasternetwork/htsecure;
index index.php;
fastcgi_index index.php;

access_log /var/log/nginx/thecoachmasternetwork.access.log;
# error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
location ~ \.user\.ini$ {
    deny all;
}
# disallow hot linking to images
location ~ .(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    valid_referers none blocked thecoachmasternetwork.com www.thecoachmasternetwork.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
# serve static files that exist
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
# send .php files to fastcgi if file exists
location ~ \.php$ {
   # Zero-day exploit defence - http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root@fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;


 }

}

    # redirects from http -> https
    #server {
    #    if ($host = www.thecoachmasternetwork.com) {
    #        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    #    if ($host = thecoachmasternetwork.com) {
    #        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    #    server_name thecoachmasternetwork.com www.thecoachmasternetwork.com;
    #    listen 80;
    #    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    
    #}
    ian@ianhobson:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$
```

I can't find a rewrite, or a return 301.

However when I request the root, or when I request /index.php, the access log shows a 301 redirect to another site on my server. This is NOT the default_site, nor is it the first site. Those have been set up in nginx.conf before the inclusion of sites-enabled/*. However on port 80 only.

I suspect its a problem with certbot's certificates, (which is why I have switched it to port 80, soI can start them again). The site redirected to, is on https, and appears to be fine.

Other information that might be useful. **/license.txt** is served correctly. A .php file containing **<php phpinfo() /php>** produces what is expected. I can see nothing strange in it. I have poked about in the WP files, and can see nothing strange there, but it is a hideously complicated site.

There is nothing in the error.log.

So what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that wordpress has two lines in the ???options table, that define the URL of the siteurl and the home page. I had not changed these, and it was wordpress that was issuing the 301.